# Eloquent modify data before retuning them

Tags: php, eloquent, php-carbon, slim-3

I want to build up something like a middleware on Eloquent.
When I make a request on my model "Event" I need to always parse the date value.

Here is what I have:

Event model:

```
class Event extends Model {
  protected $fillable = [
    'type',
    'topic',
    'teacher',
    'date',
    'endDate'
  ];
}
```

Function requesting data:

```
$event = Event::find(Todo::max('event_id'));

$date = Carbon::parse($event->date);
$date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');
$event->date = $date;
```

The point is I will need the last three lines on all request.
Where can I put them, so I don't have to copy them beyond every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel's mutators :

```
protected $casts = [
    'date' => 'datetime:Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z',
];
```

More infos here :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your Event model as follows:

```
public function getDateAttribute()
{
   $date = Carbon::parse($this->date);
   return $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');
}
```

Now whenever you call $event->date you get the modified one.

Comment: Do I also get the modified date when I call Event::all() since date is part of it?

Comment: Actually I'm getting todays date in the requested format

Comment: Yes, it should work for `Event::all()`; And it should return whatever date you have saved in your database in the requested format